# Run a function just once in StartUp.cs After application Deployment

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing ASP.NET core 2.2 web application. I want to run a function just once after the application is deployed each time in Startup.cs file.

This function slows down the application as it does some heavy checks on the application startup. I only want to run this just once each time when the application is deployed.

This is the code

```
SynapseCore.Services.Plugins.SiteContentDiscovery iCont = new SiteContentDiscovery();
            _logger.LogInformation("Startup - Complete : SiteContentDiscovery", new object[0]);

            SynapseCore.Shared.GlobalData.pluginList = pluginsInfoList;
            _logger.LogInformation("Startup - Complete : pluginList", new object[0]);

            iCont.SetPluginInfo(pluginsInfoList);
            _logger.LogInformation("Startup - Complete : SetPluginInfo", new object[0]);

        //The following function 'CheckDatabaseIntegrity' is to be run once after deployment. 
           iCont.CheckDatabaseIntegrity();
          _logger.LogInformation("Startup - Complete : CheckDatabaseIntegrity", new object[0]);

            iCont.CheckPluginStatus();
            _logger.LogInformation("Startup - Complete : CheckPluginStatus", new object[0]);

            PluginSiteComposedData composedData = iCont.CompileSiteDataList();
```

I have looked into

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
```

But doesn't seem to have that attribute i am looking for.

My question is, how do i detect through code if the application is running for the first time after deployment on IIS ?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant bits of your code? :)

Comment: @party-ring .. i have added the code. Thanks.

Comment: How about writing a file to your site directory? Write the file during first run, and then check for its existence on each run, and only do the operation if it doesn't exist. Since it's not actually part of your project, it won't exist for a newly published app. You'll want to ignore it from your source control, obviously, so you don't accidentally commit it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Thanks a lot mate, this looks promising . I'll give it a go and will give you feedback.

Comment: Thanks again Chris. It's working well. I am not sure if i can mark your comment as the correct answer. Let me know how if you would like me to mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply store and check the assembly version. If it increased you can assume that you deployed a new version.

But you also have to increase it in your project properties each time you want to deploy a new version.